# Link OK button to settings panel to add an account

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a picture that can be shared through Facebook and Twitter.

If Facebook or Twitter isn't connected with your phone, a `UIAlertAction` pops up saying you have to connect.

When I click the OK button, I would want to navigate to the settings panel from the iPhone itself and once done it should go back to the app.

How can I do this?

This is the code I have once there has been clicked on the Twitter button to share the picture.

```
func twitterClicked( sender:UIBarButtonItem ){

    if ( SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter)) {
        let twitterVC = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        presentViewController(twitterVC, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in})
        twitterVC.setInitialText("Picture shared through code made in Native Development")
        twitterVC.addImage(theView.imageView.image)
        twitterVC.addURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.devine.be"))
    } else {
        println("connecteer je twitter")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Connect", message: "Connect your twitter", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in

            println("Ok geklikt")
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) -> Void in

            println("Cancel geklikt")
        }

        alert.addAction(okAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can invoke opening Settings:

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

After that the user will have to manually return to the application.

Comment: Okay awesome! Is there an option to get him immediately to the create twitter account?

Comment: You mean you want to navigate the user to Twitter so he can open a new account?